# PHP 5.2.12 - Interesting Switch Statement Bug With Integers and Strings

Tags: php

```
<?php
$var = 0;
switch($var) {
   case "a":
      echo "I think var is a";
   break;
   case "b":
      echo "I think var is b";
   break;
   case "c":
      echo "I think var is c";
   break;
   default:
      echo "I know var is $var";
   break;
}
?>
```

Maybe someone else will find this fascinating *and* have an answer. If you run this, it outputs `I think the var is a` when *clearly* it's `0`. Now, I'm most certain this has something to do with the fact that we're using strings in our `switch` statement but the variable we're checking is an integer. Does anyone know why PHP behaves this way? It's nothing too major, but it did give me a bit of a headache today.

Thanks folks!

Comment: It's not necessarily a bug if you simply don't understand the behaviour :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you compare an `integer` with a `string`, the `string` is converted to a `number`. So effectively your snippet is equivalent to:

```
$var = 0;
switch($var) {
   case 0: // "a" gets converted to 0.
      echo "I think var is a";
   break;
   case 0: // "b" gets converted to 0.
      echo "I think var is b";
   break;
   case 0: // "c" gets converted to 0.
      echo "I think var is c";
   break;
   default:
      echo "I know var is $var";
   break;
}
```

Which will produce `I think var is a` as output as the first case body gets executed. Even though there are 3 candidates, the first one is selected because it appears at the top.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, when you compare a string and an integer, whether it be in a switch statement or using the regular comparison operators, the string is converted to an integer (unless you're using the === operator).

And when converting a string to an integer, a string that doesn't start with either a digit or a sign is always converted to 0.

See the documentation [here](http://www.php.net/ternary) and [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion).

Comment: I agree with what you said. However, doesn't explain why the first switch statement is getting activated. In the code I provided, aren't we comparing an integer to a string instead of vice versa?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Look at the first link I posted, at the table called "Comparison with Various Types". Regardless of which order the operands are in, whenever strings and numbers are compared, the strings will be converted to numbers.

Comment: A somewhat hacky way to get around this would be to switch on `true` and have the case be something like `($var === "a")`. You can switch on constants with variable cases in C; I'm pretty sure it'll work in PHP too.