# Why is the value is showing up twice when using switch statment

Tags: php

For some weird reason the value of my first case statement is showing twice, and with out a switch statement its showing once.

For example I have the following array assigned to `$validationErrors`

```
array(
[0] =>'Please select a Expiration Month'
[1] =>'Please select a Expiration Year'
['Name'] => 'This name is required'
['Phone'] => 'This Phone is required'
['Email'] => 'This Email is required'
['Credit Card Number'] => 'This Credit Card Number is required'
)
```

Below is my foreach loop I a using ...

```
  foreach ($validationErrors as $key => $error) {



  switch ($key) {

        case "Email":
            echo "email is empty!";
            break;


        case "Name":
            echo "Name is empty!";
            break;


    }
```

When I submit a form and get back an error array i see "email is empty! email is empty!"
and then "Name is empty!" just displays once.

Any idea on why that is happening? Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: var_dump($validationErrors)

Comment: @Naruto I already did that and it the key=>$error shows only once. The array I posted was a var_dump of $validationErrors

Comment: Also, why use switch when you have text in the array?  Just `echo $error;`.

Comment: I think it's because you have integers and strings. Look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611932/php-5-2-12-interesting-switch-statement-bug-with-integers-and-strings

Comment: @Nanis Thanks for your reply. You where correct it was because of the integers. I added a key value pair for the whole array and it worked!

Answer (score 4):

switch uses a loose-typed comparison, and loose-typed `0 == "Email"`

Comment: Mark. Thanks a lot for the response. That makes a whole lot of sense now. I have changed the array to use only key value pair and it works now.